# Reporting internal validation from .632 bootstrap in caret

Tags: machine-learning, bootstrap, validation, caret

I am developing Machine learning prediction models using the caret package in r (Elastic net, SVM, Random Forest, XGBoost). I have 650 cases with 104 having the event of interest. Instead of splitting the data into training and test cohorts, I have decided to use .632 bootstrap to perform internal validation.

First I perform hyperparameter tuning using repeated cross-validation, then build final models using fixed parameters (best tuned results from the cross-validation) via 'boot632' method with 1000 bootstrap samples.

I assume that the model$results gives the validated performance across the 1000 bootstrap samples, that  is performance on the held-out samples. But am I also suppose to report the performance on the held-in samples too, and if so, how do I acquire this?